# Is there a way to merge tabs in Excel without using a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I'm needing to combine worksheet tabs together to allow me to see all of my data on one page. Can it be done without using a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to combine worksheet tabs together to allow me to see all of my data

You can view multiple worksheets using the instructions below.

Note:

- This does not **combine** the worksheets. Instead it allow you to view different worksheets at the same time.

---

#### View two or more worksheets at the same time

> **View two worksheets in the same workbook side by side**
>
> 1. On the View tab, in the Window group, click New Window.
>
>    [image: The Window group on the View tab]
> 2. On the View tab, in the Window group, click View Side by Side [image: Button image].
> 3. In the workbook window, click the worksheets that you want to compare.
> 4. To scroll both worksheets at the same time, click Synchronous Scrolling [image: Synchronous Scrolling] in the Window group on the View tab.
>
>    Note: This option is available only when View Side by Side is turned
>      on.
>
> Tips
>
> - If you resize the workbook windows for optimal viewing, you can click Reset Window Position [Button image](https://osiprodweuodcspstoa01.blob.core.windows.net/en-us/media/33403ed3-ec76-4b92-b2d3-bb4e09856eb8.gif) to return to the original
>     settings.
> - To restore a workbook window to full size, click Maximize [image] at the upper-right corner of the workbook window.
>
> **View multiple worksheets at the same time**
>
> 1. Open the workbook or workbooks that contain the worksheets that you want to view at the same time.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    If the worksheets that you want to view are in the same workbook, do
>      the following:
>
>    - Click a worksheet that you want to view.
>    - On the View tab, in the Window group, click New Window.
>
>      [image]
>    - Repeat steps 1 and 2 for each sheet that you want to view.
>
>    If the worksheets that you want to view are in different workbooks,
>      continue with step 3.
> 3. On the View tab, in the Window group, click Arrange All.
> 4. Under Arrange, click the option that you want.
> 5. To view sheets only in the active workbook, select the Windows of active workbook check box.
>
> Tip
>
> - To restore a workbook window to full size, click Maximize [image] at the upper-right corner of the workbook window.

Source [View two or more worksheets at the same time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-two-or-more-worksheets-at-the-same-time-2892a172-8d6f-48e6-92fb-351b91a4dd3a)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a new sheet
solely for the purpose of displaying your data. 
For example, if you have `Sheet1`…`Sheet8`, then create a `Sheet9`. 
“Copy” the data of interest from Sheets 1-8 and “Paste Link” onto `Sheet9`. 
This will create references (e.g., `=Sheet1!Q42`) that will,
thereafter, dynamically show the data in the source cells.